# TL431 small signal analysis

Tags: tl431

I read the Chris Basso APEC 2010
[image]
I don't understand why the C1 can connect the Op amp output directly when using the TL431.

Because the TL431 output has a BJT.

[image]

Comment: Look **very carefully** at the + and - inputs of the error amplifier and which one connects to the \$V_{ref}\$. Note that the NPN inverts the output. So C1 connects between CATHODE and REF.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you mean the NPN is a common emitter so the output signal is inverted. so it looks like negative feedback?

Comment: *so it looks like negative feedback?* Do the analysis yourself, bottom picture: if the voltage at the REF, goes **up** a tiny bit, then (since REF is + input) the output of the error amp will also go up, that makes the NPN conduct {more/less} which causes the voltage at CATHODE to go {up/down}...  For circuits with feedback, you should master this skill, fortunately it is very easy to learn.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  the V+ should be the same with V- , why the V7 can get higher than V-?

Comment: What is V7? I do not see it. Have you read the datasheet of the TL431? Can you explain what it does and how it works?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Sorry, not V7. This is V+.
I have read the datasheet. in the datasheet, if V+>2.5 the BJT will turn on if V+<2.5 the BJT like an open circuit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie in the figure 23 this circuit,  V+ is the same with the V- right?